# Firebase ImageMagick convert: unable to read font

Tags: firebase, imagemagick, google-cloud-functions

I get the following error in cloud-functions when I try to run this command and I'm unsure of why the font is not detected as I did not specify one so it should use the default system font.

```
args[0] = myImagePath;
args.push('-gravity', 'center','-fill','red','-annotate',`+${text_below_x}+${text_below_y}`, 'TEST MAN');
args.push('\\(',pinPath, '-resize', pinSize, '\\)', '-gravity', 'Center', '-geometry', `+${xOffset}+${yOffset}`, '-composite');
args.push(outPutPath);

var promise = spawn('convert', args, {shell: true});
promise.childProcess.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log('[spawn] stdout:', data.toString());
})
promise.childProcess.stderr.on('data', data => {
    console.error(data.toString()); 
    reject(data.toString())
})
```

**Error:**

> convert: unable to read font `(null)' @
>   error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1127.

**Error Persists when a Font is defined:**

> convert: unable to read font 'Arial' @
>   warning/annotate.c/RenderType/872. convert: unable to read font
>   `Arial' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1127.

Comment: I do not see where you specify the font to use. Some systems do not have a default font. Best to specify a font file with the path to it, rather than a font name. If you need names, then the type.xml file needs to be modified to include the fonts that are available on your system that Imagemagick can use. If you want to use Arial, then use the path to arial.ttf.

Comment: @fmw42 unfortunately a relative url pointing to a font file on the deployed instance didn't work. Same error.

Comment: @fmw42 okay good news. Putting the font file in the same exact folder as the function worked. But now I get this error `convert: unable to open image 'Man': No such file or directory` where 'Man' is actually a part of the string that I'm trying to annotate onto the image while I composite.

Comment: Put your text string that is to be annotated in quotes.

Comment: I did. `'Text-Man'` works fine but `'Text Man'` leads to imagemagick treating `Man` as a filename. I updated my code above to show exactly how it's being entered.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that the node.js child-process is stripping the quotation marks. I will try escaping them.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I got it working. I had to escape the text so it became `'\'Text Man\''` and moving the font into the same folder as my script and using `'-font' , 'myfont.ttf'` solved the original problem. Thanks for all your help.

Feel free to submit your suggestions as the answer and I'll close this.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I got it working. I had to escape the text so it became ''Text Man'' and moving the font into the same folder as my script and using '-font' , 'myfont.ttf' solved the original problem. Thanks for all your help. Feel free to submit your suggestions as the answer and I'll close this.